# Creating a view from another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, view

I want to create a view from another table..

Current view has the following content(image 1):

[image]

Trying to get an output from the above view as shown(image 2), i.e. grouping the values from those columns:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Individual queries work, such as :
                                       select w1,count(*) from 'table_name' group by w1 and so on. 

but im not sure how to combine the queries to get this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT bucket,
  COUNTIF(col = 0) AS w1,
  COUNTIF(col = 1) AS w2,
  COUNTIF(col = 2) AS w3,
  COUNTIF(col = 3) AS w4
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, 
  UNNEST([w1, w2, w3, w4]) bucket WITH OFFSET col
GROUP BY bucket
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to unpivot the data and then re-aggregate:

```
select w,
       sum(case when i = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as w1,
       sum(case when i = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as w2,
       sum(case when i = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as w3,
       sum(case when i = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as w4
from (select array[w1, w2, w3, w4] ws
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(ws) w with offset i
group by w;
```

Here is a more complete example:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as slno, '<5' as w1, '<5' as w2, '<5' as w3, '<5' as w4 union all
      select 1 as slno, '<5' as w1, '5 to 10' as w2, '<5' as w3, '5 to 10' as w4 
     )
select w,
       sum(case when i = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as w1,
       sum(case when i = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as w2,
       sum(case when i = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as w3,
       sum(case when i = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as w4
from (select array[w1, w2, w3, w4] as ws
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(ws) w with offset i
group by w;
```

Comment: This is an example i gave with just 5 rows. However, the actual table has around 1k rows. Would there be another way to sum up the values for large count?

Comment: @user10173721 . . . The number of rows plays no role in this.  All the rows are summed up.